# Delphi ListView DynamicAppearance how to specify the color of the text of one Item in code?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

How can I change the `TextColor` property in a Delphi TlistView DynamicAppearance?

Here is my code to add an Item and text

```
function TForm1.Remplissage_ListViewNews(debut_news, fin_news:Integer) :Integer;
var
 _Image,_Title,_Location, _Infos,_Details,_Url:TField;
 _Item: TListViewItem;

begin

     MySQLQuery_News.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM news' + ' LIMIT '+IntToStr(debut_news)+','+IntToStr(fin_news);
     MySQLQuery_News.Active   :=  True;
     MySQLQuery_News.Open;

     if MySQLQuery_News.RecordCount > 0 then
        begin
            MySQLQuery_News.First;
            MySQLQuery_News.DisableControls;

            _Image    := MySQLQuery_News.FieldByName('id_news');
            _Title    := MySQLQuery_News.FieldByName('nom_expo');
            _Location := MySQLQuery_News.FieldByName('location');
            _Infos    := MySQLQuery_News.FieldByName('infos');
            _Details  := MySQLQuery_News.FieldByName('commentaire_fr');
            _Url      := MySQLQuery_News.FieldByName('url_fr');


            try

              ListView_News.BeginUpdate;
              ListView_News.EditMode := True;
              ListView_News.Visible  := false;

              while (not MySQLQuery_News.EOF) do begin
                _Item := ListView_News.Items.Add;
                _Item.Data['Title']   := _Title.AsString;
                _Item.Data['Infos']   := _Location.AsString + ' - ' + _Infos.AsString;
                _Item.Data['Details'] := copy(_Details.AsString,1,350);
                _Item.Data['Url']     := _Url.AsString;
                _Item.Data['Image']   := RecupereImage(Image_url + 'news/'+ _Image.AsString + '.jpg');
                MySQLQuery_News.Next;
              end;

            finally

              MySQLQuery_News.EnableControls;
              ListView_News.Visible  := True;
              ListView_News.EditMode := False;
              ListView_News.EndUpdate;

            end;

           Result := ListView_News.ITems.Count;

        end
        else
        begin
            showmessage('Aucun enregistrement trouvé');
            Result := 0;
        end;

 end;
```

I would like to specify by code the `TextColor` property for each text Item because in my case ( Android application ) the parameter TextColor using the Conception mode do not work until I change the orientation of my smartphone! Incredible ...

Does someone have a solution to make the TextColor parameter work or to put it in the code ?

Thanks a lot if someone could help me

Comment: Thank's for your help
I have removed the pictures and put the complete code of my function

Comment: You can use OnUpdateObjects to do this. There is a sample and this blog post has an example. https://blogs.embarcadero.com/variable-item-height-with-tlistview-in-10-1-berlin/

Comment: Thank's a lot :)